# Deletar milhares de registro de uma tabela

Tags: sql, oracle, delete, oracle11g

Tenho uma tabela, por exemplo, `pessoa`, e gostaria de **deletar todas as pessoas acima de 40 anos**, com o *script* abaixo faço isso:

```
DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE pessoa.idade > 40;
```

O problema que existe mais de **2 milhões de registro na tabela**, com 
pessoas acima de 40 anos, e como o banco esta em produção, ao fazer
isso vou travar todos os usuários.

Existe uma forma mais eficiente de resolver este problema?

Comment: Podes fazer um limit á query `DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE pessoa.idade > 40 LIMIT 5000` e fazer um script para executar esta query em x segundos até não existirem linhas

Comment: Seguindo mais ou menos a mesma linha de raciocínio que o lazyFox disse, esse tópico aqui também diz, pra criar arquivos batch e executar de pouco em pouco: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785439/deleting-1-millions-rows-in-sql-server

Comment: A tabela tem fk´s que dependam dela ? Quantos registros ficariam na tabela ? Existem soluções como exportar o que vai ficar num script de insert , truncate na tabela e importar , abrir o bd exclusivo , desligar o audit , deletar , ligar o audit e reabrir o bd

Comment: Copiar Dados que interessam para NovaTabela e deletar ou renomear a TabelaAntiga e renomear a NovaTabela para TabelaAntiga :)

Comment: @Motta, me confundi com a tabela, ela tem 4 fk, e 6 indexes, ficariam com 82 milhões.

Comment: talvez seja melhor algo como : salva os registros que devem ficar em scripts de insert , desabilita as constraints , dá truncate nas tabelas , realiza o script de (re)insert , habitita as constrainsts , em todo caso pesquise em sites como o asktom pois tem farto material sobre isto.

Comment: O problema de inserir esses dados novamente, com os scripts de insert, é que são muitos inserts para serem feitos, vai demorar pra caramba.

Acredito que a opção do @lazyFox é a melhor, pois limitando o número de exclusões, não vai ficar tão pesado para o sistema e muito menos para os usuários!

Comment: Estou longe de ser um conhecedor profundo de Oracle e SQL. Porém, acho que cabem duas perguntinhas relevantes: 1) essa remoção é algo que ocorre com frequência durante a operação? 2) essa remoção precisa ser imediata? Pergunto isso porque talvez você possa simplesmente marcar esses registros como irrelevantes (pendentes para exclusão) e rodar uma procedure durante a noite (ou em um horário de baixa utilização do sistema) para fazer a remoção propriamente dita.

Comment: A operação não ocorre com frequência, mas ocorre ocasionalmente. Sim a operação precisa ser feita de maneira imediata. Obrigado Luiz.

Comment: @lazyFox, o duro que preciso remover todos de uma vez, e fazer de x e x segundos, dividindo 2kk/5k seria 6 minutos, não seria tão ruim assim, mas queria algo na casa de segundos.. obrigado

Comment: Como a operação ocorre ocasionalmente: primeiro elimina os que já existem. E a partir de aí sempre que inserir novos registos apaga  também os com a condição que deseja, neste caso `> 40`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Você deveria proceder com operações paralelas, se tive um processador bom pode executar da seguinte forma:

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
DELETE /*+ parallel(pessoa, 20) */
  FROM  pessoa
  WHERE idade > 40;
```

Segue o link do [site da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96520/tuningpe.htm) onde fala sobre paralelização de processos, outra [boa referência](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/oracle-parallel-processing/156592701X/ch04s02.html), e mais uma referência de [como deletar grandes quantidades de informação](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689).

---

Na minha opinião , trabalho com bancos bem grandes com mais de 100 milhões de registros. Um delete desses que você quer fazer não deve demorar mais que 2 ou 3 minutos se o seu servidor for bom.

Comment: Obrigado, @Jaser pela resposta, vou ler a documentação e testar.

Comment: executei um teste em outra tabela com 800k e demorou 19s, muito interessante, vou aguardar mais alguma resposta, caso contrario vou rodar a sua sugestão na tabela principal. Obrigado

Comment: obrigado ^^ só postei isso aqui pois é assim que eu trabalho com meus bancos. Lembrando que ele cria uma Thread paralela então ele da prioridade de processamento mas ele alterna com outros processos , não é um processo em paralelo real.

Comment: conseguiu fazer o que queria?? ^^

Answer (score 7):

Não sou especialista em oracle, mas você também pode criar uma tabela com os registros que você quer **manter**.

Algo como:

```
create table pessoa_new as select * from pessoa where idade <= 40;
```

Depois disso, execute um truncate na tabela **original**:

```
truncate table pessoa
```

> Note que o truncate não cria log no oracle, isto é, você não vai
>   conseguir fazer rollback ou commit. Uma vez feito, não pode ser
>   desfeito.

Depois disso, copie os dados de volta para a tabela original:

```
alter session set rollback_segment = 'HUGE_RBS';   

insert into pessoa as select * from pessoa_new
```

Ou se preferir, troque o nome da tabela nova e antiga:

```
alter table pessoa rename to pessoa_old;
alter table pessoa_new rename to pessoa;
```

Em qualquer um dos casos, lembre-se de *rebuildar* os indexes e caso escolha renomear as tabelas, considere recriar constraints, triggers, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Ao invés de você rodar o delete para deletar todos os registros, você pode criar uma PL e ir deletando aos poucos e realizando o commit a cada x registros, isso vai evitar que "trave" os outros usuários.

```
declare
  cursor c is select p.rowid r from pessoa p where p.idade > 40;
  c_commit number:= 0;
  l_commit number:= 10000;
  begin
    for t in c 
    loop
      c_commit := c_commit + 1;
      delete from pessoa p where p.rowid = t.r;

      if mod( c_commit, l_commit ) = 0 then
        commit;
      end if;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

A solução do Aron Linhares funciona bem, só acrescentaria o uso do BULK COLLECT para melhorar o desempenho.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C_CURSOR IS SELECT P.ROWID AS CHAVE FROM PESSOA P WHERE P.IDADE > 40;
  TYPE TYPE_CURSOR IS TABLE OF C_CURSOR%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  R_CURSOR    TYPE_CURSOR;       
  BEGIN
    OPEN C_CURSOR;
      LOOP
      --preeche a memória de 1000 em 1000 registros
        FETCH C_CURSOR BULK COLLECT INTO R_CURSOR LIMIT 1000;
        EXIT WHEN R_CURSOR.COUNT = 0;
          FOR I IN 1 .. R_CURSOR.COUNT
          LOOP 
              DELETE FROM PESSOA P WHERE P.ROWID = R_CURSOR(I).CHAVE;
          END LOOP;
          --VAI APLICAR COMMIT DE 1000 EM 1000;
          COMMIT;
     END LOOP C_CURSOR;
    CLOSE C_CURSOR;
END;
/
```

Na documentação do [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html), você encontrará mais detalhes sobre como trabalhar com grande massa de dados em PL/SQL.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html